# Windows won't accept PIN after power outage, doesn't show an option to put in password

Tags: windows, windows-10, login, login-screen

(This is a complicated one, as I'm supporting my parents over the phone with this)

My parents' home computer shut down due to a power outage. Now, when they turn it on, the login screen says that they've put in the wrong PIN and asks them to type in `A1B2C3` -
[image]

Once they do that, it asks them for their PIN again, and when putting that in (they're certain it's the right one), and following that it says `This sign-in option is disabled because of failed sign-in attempts or repeated shutdowns. Use a different sign-in option, or keep your device powered on for at least 2 hours and then try again.`

Yet, there is no other sign-in option. Specifically, there is no way to enter a password.

Any idea how we could get them to use their computer again?

**More information and things we tried**

- There is only one admin account on the computer, so they can't log in with a different account (I'll remedy that as soon as we're back in)
- I tried to do a System Restore (by restarting the computer whilst holding shift), but it asked for a password and rejected any password we put in. I've reset my father's password through Microsoft's website, but it seems like the computer hasn't fetched the new password.
- Tried to log in in safe mode, but the same process with PIN repeated itself.
- When on the log-in screen, the computer is connected to the internet (through WiFi)

Any idea what we can do?
Seems like the PIN is borked and I'm looking for a way to log in with a password (preferably one that will fetch the new password from Microsoft)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a Microsoft Account.

On a different computer, go to Microsoft Live Login  (type that in Google)  Looks like this:  https://account.microsoft.com/account?lang=en-hk

Enter the email address that your parents use.

Then use the "Forgot Password" routine, make a new password and then on your parents' computer, log in with the new password.

Once you have changed the password and they can log in, they can reset or make a new PIN at the computer.

Comment: The problem is, there is no place to put the password in. I.e., there's no option to change the PIN input into a password one.

Comment: On the computer, yes, but on Microsoft Live you can click on "Forgot Password" and change it. You do not need a PIN at this point normally. Microsoft Live is web based and works an a different computer.

Comment: Thanks John. What I meant is that I've reset the password on Microsoft live (using a different computer), but there's no place to input it on their computer. Their computer only gives the option of putting in a PIN

Comment: They might need to contact Microsoft Support. You can change password without PIN so they may need to help your folks.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting two hours (whilst the computer is on) did the trick.
Thanks for everyone who tried to help

Comment: I provided the method you needed and that is what you did (took some time) so I hope you will mark my answer as helpful.  Thanks.